# How to extract multi-digit numbers from a string?

Tags: c, string, string-parsing

Firstly, I know similar questions have been asked before but I believe my case is different.

My input string is:

> (5,7) (1,6) (2,4) (10,14) (8,9)

I wrote the following code for extraction into an array.

```
main(){
char s[100];
int i=0,x,n=0;
int a[20];
printf("Enter the sets:");
gets(s);
x=strlen(s);
while(i<x){
    if((s[i]=='(' && s[i+2]==',') || (s[i]==',' && s[i+2]==')'))
    {
        a[n]=s[i+1]-'0';
        n++;
    }   
    i++;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
}
```

The output I get is:

> 5 7 1 6 2 4 8 9

I understand why my code will skip numbers having 2 or more digits.
Please suggest some minor changes to the present code to fix this limitation.

P.S.- I'm looking for a solution which doesn't depend on length of the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only care about the numbers and not any of the delimiters, you can use `strtok`, which allows for a set of delimiters.

Use the following in place of you existing `while` loop:

```
char *p = strtok(s, "(), ");
while (p) {
    a[n++] = atoi(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, "(), ");
}
```

Output:

```
5
7
1
6
2
4
10
14
8
9
```

If on the other hand you are particular about the format, you can do the following:

```
char *start = s, *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL, *p3 = NULL;
if (start) p1 = strchr(start, '(');
if (p1) p2 = strchr(p1+1, ',');
if (p2) p3 = strchr(p2+1, ')');
while (p1 && p2 && p3) {
    a[n++] = atoi(p1+1);
    a[n++] = atoi(p2+1);
    start = p3+1;
    if (start) p1 = strchr(start, '(');
    if (p1) p2 = strchr(p1+1, ',');
    if (p2) p3 = strchr(p2+1, ')');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach to the problem, but I have solved it and it works. Consider trying this. Btw I have used char *s as a string literal but you can keep it like yours.

```
main(){

  char *s="(5,7) (1,6) (2,4) (10,14) (8,9)";
  int i=0,x,n=0;
  char a[20];
  x=strlen(s);
  while(i<x){

    if (isdigit(s[i])) {
      a[n]=s[i];
      if (s[i+1]==',' || s[i+1]==')') {
        a[n+1]=' ';
        n++;
      }
      n++;
    }
      i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

output:

```
tenshi@mashiro:~/projects/test$ ./test 
5 7 1 6 2 4 10 14 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
char s[100];
int i=0,x,n=0;
int a[20];
printf("Enter the sets:");
gets(s);
x=strlen(s);
while(i<x-1){
    if(isdigit(s[i]))
    {
        if(isdigit(s[i+1]))
        {
            a[n]=(s[i]-'0')*10  +(s[i+1]-'0');
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[n]=s[i]-'0';
        }
        n++;
    }   
    i++;
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

What about the above code, unfortunately C doesn't have simple string functions like split with Regex(it has split function but i didn't understand well). Alternatively, here is ideone for it https://ideone.com/eRKTbD

Comment: Why so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If the input is in the exact format as in the question, then you can add two loops inside the main while loop to read one set at a time.

```
while (i < x)
{
    if (s[i] == '(')
    {
        // temporary var to store number
        int num = 0;

        // read first number
        while (s[++i] != ',')
            num = num*10 + s[i]-'0';
        a[n++] = num;

        num = 0;
        // read second number
        while (s[++i] != ')')
            num = num*10 + s[i]-'0';
        a[n++] = num;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest not to accept this as answer, because it's not correct. It's correct only for 2 digits numbers, but when it comes to 3 digits and more, it's not working properly. There are plenty of good answers below.

Comment: @Mirakurun - Code works for more than two digit numbers if the input is in exact format as in the question. Can you please provide the test cases which broke the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the same format (a,b)(c,d)...(y,z) and the same number of values then this solution works :

```
char * arr = "(5,7)(1,6)(2,4)(10,14)(8,9)";
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;

sscanf(arr,"(%d,%d)(%d,%d)(%d,%d)(%d,%d)(%d,%d)",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f,&g,&h,&i,&j);

printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
```